# C# Linq Weighted Average Based on Date

Tags: c#, linq

I've found several posts detailing how to perform a weighted average based on a foreign key, but I have yet to find a solution that deals with my situation.  Here it is:

I have two tables, table A and a table B many-to-many table linking them; nothing complicated:

```
TableA
{
     A_ID,
     Other stuff
}

TableB
{
     B_ID,
     Date
     Other stuff
}

LinkAtoB
{
     A_ID,
     B_ID
}
```

Now here comes the math part.  I'm more or less trying to weight result from TableA based on the number of recent associations in Table B.

So if TableA has 4 associations in table with the following dates:

```
{10/23/2010, //3 days ago
10/19/2010,  //5 days ago
10/18/2010,  //6 days ago
9/13/2010}   //40ish days ago
```

So here is how I'd like to rank them:

I'd like to provide a recency threshold in days, I'll use 7 days as an example:

So using the above data I would assign the following values:

```
{10/23/2010, //7-3 = 4
10/19/2010,  //7-5 = 2
10/18/2010,  //7-6 = 1
9/13/2010}   //40ish days ago
```

So the value of the weighted average for that particular TableA entry is then 7 / 3 = 2.33333.

Here is more or less what I have so far:

```
var k = from a in TableA
        group a by a.Select(x=>x.LinkAtoB.TableB)
                    .Where(x=>x.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)) >= 0)
                    into g
        select g.Sum(x => DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.Date).Days) / 
        g.Sum(x => x.Length);
```

I think I'm close but I know I have the group part wrong.  I think the other stuff should work.  How do I fix my code to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go! :)

```
var k = (from b in TableB
        join bb in LinkAtoB on b.B_ID equals bb.B_ID into b_join
        from ab in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where b.B_DATE.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)) > 0
        select new {ab.A_ID, DaysAgo = (DateTime.Now - b.B_DATE).Days} into xx
        group xx by xx.A_ID into yy
        select new {yy.Key, Weighted = yy.Sum(x=> 7 - x.DaysAgo) / yy.Count()} into zz
        join a in TableA on zz.Key equals a.A_ID
        select new {a.A_ID, a.A_Other_Stuff, zz.Weighted}).ToList();
```

Comment: GOLDEN!  This totally works except for one minor edit.  The .Value is not necessary on the 5th line.  Other than that smooth sailing.  The DefaultIfEmpty() part was what was killing me.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for leaving that in. I was testing with a nullable date. Removed now. Glad it works :)